# Comparing Performance of ARRAY_AGG() vs. ROW_NUMBER() for Deduplication in BigQuery on Large Datasets

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working with Google BigQuery and exploring different methods for data deduplication in large datasets. I have experience using both `ARRAY_AGG()` with `[OFFSET(0)]` and `ROW_NUMBER()` for this purpose. Based on my observations, I've found that `ARRAY_AGG()` with `[OFFSET(0)]`, even when incorporating ordering criteria, tends to offer better performance compared to `ROW_NUMBER()` on large datasets. I am keen to understand if this experience aligns with that of others in the community.

Here's a brief overview of the two methods I'm comparing:

1. Using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

- `ROW_NUMBER()` over a window partition, often combined with `ORDER BY` to establish criteria for which duplicates to retain.
- Example: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) as rn`, then filter on `rn = 1`.

2. Using ARRAY_AGG() with [OFFSET(0)]:

- `ARRAY_AGG()` with an `ORDER BY` clause within the aggregate function to specify which duplicate to keep.
- Example: `ARRAY_AGG(column ORDER BY date DESC)[OFFSET(0)]` to keep the latest record.

Questions:

1. Have others experienced similar performance results with `ARRAY_AGG()` outperforming `ROW_NUMBER()` in large datasets?
2. Are there specific conditions or types of data where `ARRAY_AGG()` is more efficient than `ROW_NUMBER()` for deduplication?
3. Could BigQuery optimizations or specific query execution strategies be favoring `ARRAY_AGG()` in such scenarios?
4. I am interested in both empirical experiences and any insights or explanations regarding the underlying mechanics of BigQuery that might account for this observation.

Any insights or shared experiences regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I think the differences in the performance are mostly from `group by` and `partition by`. The `partition by` will return all rows and the execution plan is much more complicated, compared to `group by` clause

for deduplication, the `where` clause ran on all the returned rows if partitioned while `group by` already selected the first result in the returned set.

so it is about `partition by` and `group by` behavior